# Geopandas save shapefile in memory using bytesIO or equivelent (python3X)

Tags: geopandas, bytesio

Imagine that I am manipulating a shapefile in geopandas. I then want to load it using another library (like networkx) but since my file is large I dont want to have to save and reload it. Is there a way I can save it in memory? I imagine it would look something like this:

```py
import geopandas 
from io import BytesIO 

writeBytes = BytesIO()
### load the demo
world = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
### do something trivial to the demo
world['geometry'] = world['geometry'].buffer(0.05)
### save to bytes IO so that I can do something else with it without having to save and read a file 
world.to_file(writeBytes)
```

Running the above yields a TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.BytesIO
This is the full traceback:

```
            TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
            <ipython-input-1-1ba22f23181a> in <module>
                  8 world['geometry'] = world['geometry'].buffer(0.05)
                  9 ### save to bytes IO so that I can do something else with it without having to save and read a file                                                                                           
            ---> 10 world.to_file(writeBytes)

            ~/.conda/envs/geopandas/lib/python3.7/site-packages/geopandas/geodataframe.py in to_file(self, filename, driver, schema, **kwargs)
                427         """
                428         from geopandas.io.file import to_file
            --> 429         to_file(self, filename, driver, schema, **kwargs)
                430 
                431     def to_crs(self, crs=None, epsg=None, inplace=False):

            ~/.conda/envs/geopandas/lib/python3.7/site-packages/geopandas/io/file.py in to_file(df, filename, driver, schema, **kwargs)
                125     if schema is None:
                126         schema = infer_schema(df)
            --> 127     filename = os.path.abspath(os.path.expanduser(filename))
                128     with fiona_env():
                129         with fiona.open(filename, 'w', driver=driver, crs=df.crs,

            ~/.conda/envs/geopandas/lib/python3.7/posixpath.py in expanduser(path)
                233     """Expand ~ and ~user constructions.  If user or $HOME is unknown,
                234     do nothing."""
            --> 235     path = os.fspath(path)
                236     if isinstance(path, bytes):
                237         tilde = b'~'
```

Any assistance is appreciated, Thank You

Comment: *I imagine it would look something like this* so what happens when you do that?

Comment: @PaulH I get a TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.BytesIO

Comment: That kind of info belongs in the question, along with a full traceback

Comment: @PaulH Thats fair, ill edit the question to include that information

Comment: can i ask what you're really trying to get at here? if you have the shapefile in a geodataframe, it's already in memory. you should be able to extract what you need from that and pass directory to networkx

Answer (score -1):

geopandas.to_file() requires a file path, not a BytesIO object.

Use a temporary file (or folder for shape files)
For example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70254174/2023941