# Exporting a Geopandas dataframe to a zipped shapefile directly

Tags: python, zip, shapefile, geopandas

I'm trying to save Geopandas data frame into a shapefile that is written to a zipped folder directly.

As any shapefile user knows, a shapefile is not a single file but rather a collection of files that are meant to be read together. So calling  `myGDF.to_file(filename='myshapefile.shp', driver='ESRI Shapefile')` creates not only `myshapefile.shp` but also `myshapefile.prj`, `myshapefile.dbf`, `myshapefile.shx` and `myshapefile.cpg`. This is probably why I am struggling to get the syntax right here.

Consider for instance a dummy Geopandas Dataframe like:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point

data = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'property': ['foo', 'bar', 'foo'],
        'x': [173994.1578792833, 173974.1578792833, 173910.1578792833],
        'y': [444135.6032947102, 444186.6032947102, 444111.6032947102]})
geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(data['x'], data['y'])]
myGDF = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data, geometry=geometry)
```

I saw people using `gzip`, so I tried:

```
import geopandas as gpd
myGDF.to_file(filename='myshapefile.shp.gz', driver='ESRI Shapefile',compression='gzip')
```

But it did not work.

Then I tried the following (in a Google Colab environment):

```
import zipfile
pathname = '/content/'
filename = 'myshapefile.shp'
zip_file = 'myshapefile.zip'
with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file, 'w') as zipf:
   zipf.write(myGDF.to_file(filename = '/content/myshapefile.shp', driver='ESRI Shapefile'))
```

But it only saves the `.shp` file in a zip folder, while the rest is written next to the zip folder.

How can I write a Geopandas DataFrame as a zipped shapefile directly?

Comment: Your `myGDF.to_file(...` method will return `None`, while the input of `zipf.write` must be a string, so that will never work. I also doubt you were getting any files written inside the zip file with that code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply use `zip` as a file extension, keeping the name of the driver:

```py
myGDF.to_file(filename='myshapefile.shp.zip', driver='ESRI Shapefile')
```

This should work with GDAL 3.1 or newer.

Comment: I get a (non-compressed) folder called `myshapefile.zip`. GDAL 3.3.1

Comment: This is close - the extension has to be either .shz or .shp.zip, like `myGDF.to_file(filename='myshapefile.shp.zip')`

https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/shapefile.html#compressed-files

Answer (score 6):

Something like this would work for you - dump the shapefile(s) to a fresh new tempdir and then zip up everything inside that tempdir.

```py
import tempfile
import zipfile
from pathlib import Path

with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as temp_dir:

    temp_dir = Path(temp_dir)

    # geodataframe.to_file(str(d / "myshapefile.shp"))
    with open(temp_dir / "a.shp", "w") as _f:
        _f.write("blah")
    with open(temp_dir / "a.prj", "w") as _f:
        _f.write("blah")

    with zipfile.ZipFile('myshapefile.zip', 'w') as zipf:
        for f in temp_dir.glob("*"):
            zipf.write(f, arcname=f.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

To create a zipped shapefile from a Geopandas dataframe

```
import shutil
import tempfile
from pathlib import Path
#gdf = some geopandas dataframe

with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as temp_dir:
  temp_dir = Path(temp_dir)
  localFile = 'myshapefile'

  gdf.to_file(filename=temp_dir, driver='ESRI Shapefile')

  archiveFile = shutil.make_archive(localFile, 'zip', temp_dir)
  shutil.rmtree(temp_dir)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I made it work in 2 lines of code.
Assuming that `gdf` is your geopandasdataframe.

```
import shutil
#this first line creates a new folder "gdf-folder" with the shape-files (unfortunatly also with the -folder in the name): gdf-folder.shp, gdf-folder.dbf...).
gdf.to_file("gdf-folder", driver="ESRI Shapefile")

#this second line compresses the files from the folder to a .zip file. named: gdf-zipfile.zip. Inside the .zip file the filenames are gdf-folder.shp; gdf-folder.dbf, ...)
shutil.make_archive("gdf-zipfile", "zip", "gdf-folder")
```

- You might want to remove `-folder` and `-zipfile` in the
  filenames of your code. I just tried to make clear what is associated
  with eachother in both lines of code.
- The new folder `gdf-folder` with the `gdf-folder.shp` files
  is still in your directory you can find in the windows-explorer.
- I think, by defeault, the new folder is created in the same directory as your python-scriptfile.